# How to see the following Taylor expansion?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

$f$ is a function such that $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$, and function $\boldsymbol{g}:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n:\delta\mapsto\boldsymbol{q}\cos\|\boldsymbol{\delta}\| + \frac{\boldsymbol{\delta}}{\|\boldsymbol{\delta}\|}\sin\|\boldsymbol{\delta}\|$, where the constant vector $\boldsymbol{q}\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Here obviously $\boldsymbol{g}(\boldsymbol{0}) = \boldsymbol{q}$.

Assume all involved derivatives exist. In a small neighbourhood of $\boldsymbol{0}$, consider the Taylor expansion to quadratic term of the function $$f\big(\boldsymbol{g}(\boldsymbol{\delta})\big) = f\bigg(\boldsymbol{q}\cos\|\boldsymbol{\delta}\| + \frac{\boldsymbol{\delta}}{\|\boldsymbol{\delta}\|}\sin\|\boldsymbol{\delta}\|  \bigg)$$.

We use the notation $\nabla f|_{\boldsymbol{q}}$ to mean gradient of $f$ evaluated at the point $\boldsymbol{q}$, and similar for Hessian $\nabla^2 f|_\boldsymbol{q}$.

How do I see the following:
$$f\big(\boldsymbol{g}(\boldsymbol{0}+\boldsymbol{\delta})\big) \approx f(\boldsymbol{q}) +
\langle \nabla\boldsymbol{f}|_{\boldsymbol{q}}\,,\boldsymbol{\delta}\rangle + \frac{1}{2}\boldsymbol{\delta}^T\bigg( \nabla^2f|_{\boldsymbol{q}} - \langle\nabla f|_{\boldsymbol{q}}\,,q\rangle \boldsymbol{I} \bigg)\boldsymbol{\delta}  $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, observe we have
\begin{align}
f(g(0+\delta)) =  f\left(q+ Dg(0)\delta+\frac{1}{2!}\delta^TD^2g(t^\ast\delta)\delta\right)=: f(q + \Delta)
\end{align}
for some $0<t^\ast<1$. Here where I have used the first order Taylor expansion with Lagrange remainder
\begin{align}
g(x+h) = g(x) + Dg(x)h+\frac{1}{2}h^TD^2g(x+t^\ast h) h.
\end{align}
Next, again using first order Taylor expansion with Lagrange remainder we see
\begin{align}
f(q+\Delta)= f(q) + Df(q)\Delta + \frac{1}{2!}\Delta^TD^2f(q+\theta^\ast \Delta)\Delta.
\end{align}
where $0<\theta^\ast<1$. Note that $D^2f$ is a bilinear form  which takes in two vectors which in our case is $\Delta$ and $\Delta$ (in this case, it's just a matrix). Hence it follows
\begin{align}
f(g(0+\delta)) =&\ f(q) + Df(q)\left[Dg(0)\delta+\frac{1}{2}\delta^TD^2g(t^\ast\delta)\delta\right]\\
&+\frac{1}{2!}\left[Dg(0)\delta+\frac{1}{2!}\delta^TD^2g(t^\ast\delta)\delta\right]^T[ D^2f(q+\theta^\ast \Delta)]\left[Dg(0)\delta+\frac{1}{2!}\delta^TD^2g(t^\ast\delta)\delta\right].
\end{align}
Since everything is as smooth as a like and $\|\delta\|$ is a small as a want, then it follows that
\begin{align}
D^2g(t^\ast\delta)\approx D^2g(0), \ \ \text{ and } \ \ D^2f(q+\theta^\ast \Delta)\approx D^2f(q)
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
f(g(0+\delta)) \approx&\ f(q) + Df(q)\left[Dg(0)\delta+\frac{1}{2!}\delta^TD^2g(0)\delta\right] \\
&+ \frac{1}{2!} \left[Dg(0)\delta+\frac{1}{2!}\delta^TD^2g(0)\delta\right]^T[D^2f(q)]\left[Dg(0)\delta+\frac{1}{2!}\delta^TD^2g(0)\delta\right]\\
\approx&\ f(q)+Df(q)[Dg(0)\delta]+\frac{1}{2!}Df(q)[\delta^T D^2g(0)\delta]+\frac{1}{2!}[Dg(0)\delta]^T [D^2f(q)][Dg(0)\delta]\\
&+ \mathcal{O}(\|\delta\|^3)
\end{align}
Finally, note that
\begin{align}
Dg(0)\delta=\frac{d}{dt}g(t\delta)\bigg|_{t=0} =&\ \frac{d}{dt}\left[q \cos(t\|\delta\|)+ \frac{\delta}{\|\delta\|} \sin(t\|\delta\|)\right]\bigg|_{t=0}\\
=&\ -q\|\delta\|\sin(t\|\delta\|)+ \delta\cos(t\|\delta\|)\bigg|_{t=0} =\delta
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\delta^TD^2g(0)\delta = \frac{d^2}{dt^2}g(t\delta)\bigg|_{t=0} = -\|\delta\|^2q = - (\delta^T\delta)\ q 
\end{align}
Combining everything gives us the desired result
\begin{align}
f(g(\delta)) \approx&\ f(q) + Df(q)\delta-\frac{1}{2!}(\delta^T\delta)Df(q)q + \frac{1}{2!} \delta^T D^2f(q)\delta\\
 &=\ f(q) + Df(q)\delta +\frac{1}{2!}\delta^T\left(D^2f(q) - Df(q)[q] I\right)\delta
\end{align}